# Чем обусловлено ограничение на повторное голосование за комментарий?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, голосование

Почему существует такое ограничение? Чем оно обусловлено? Что плохого в повторном голосовании?

Comment: На ответы так-то тоже есть ограничение.

Comment: Накрутка? Количество голосов на комментарии будет ограничено лишь наличием желания и времени голосующего, а не будет зависеть от количества согласных с комментарием. Тоже самое можно сказать и про голосование за вопросы/ответы

Comment: а что хорошего в повторном голосований?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет, он не это имел в виду. С ответа ты можешь снять голос, а потом поставить снова. А если ты с комментария снимешь плюс, то проголосовать повторно за него уже нельзя. Накрутить ничего таким способом не получится.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так комментарии нельзя редактировать (свежие правки в расчет не берём)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде бы где-то видел на MSE, может потом найду ссылку, подход с голосованием на комментариях такой же как и на сообщениях в общих чертах. То есть голос через некоторое время замораживается до последующего изменения сообщения. А учитывая, что комментарии можно править автору только первые 5 минут после публикации (если это не модератор, конечно) особого смысла в переголосованиях нет, так как текст, за которой отдается голос уже не может измениться. Дополнительно здесь ещё стоит упомянуть, что комментарии вторичны, на SO их не ценят (не дают репутацию), а порой и просто удаляют за ненадобностью без каких-либо уведомлений. При большом количестве комментариев под сообщением система вовсе предлагает перенести их в чат. В случае переноса все голоса теряются, кстати.